# Can't figure out this Obj-C to Swift conversion

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiwebview

I'm following a tutorial on how to implement the instagram API and I'm stuck on a few parts. Converting the Obj-C to Swift as I go, thought I understood what i was unto but clearly not.

This part is currently giving me an issue, I can't put these constants all together in a `NSString(format: .. , args: ...)`

`NSString *fullURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@&redirect_uri= %@&response_type=token",KAUTHURL,KCLIENTID,kREDIRECTURI];`

and I cannot get the UIWebView.loadRequest to load the fullURL variable

Any help would be appreciated!

ANSWER:

```
import UIKit

class OAuthViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var myWebView: UIWebView?

    var savedToken = ""
    var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    var KAUTHURL: String = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/"
    var kAPIURl: String = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/"
    var KCLIENTID: String = "02627256292c4083a42e55db3ef21a82"
    var KCLIENTSERCRET: String = "15d0c073b82545d7b000fdf8440bf0c6"
    var KREDIRECTURI: String = "https://www.chahooo.tumblr.com"
    var KSCOPEADD: String = "&scope=relationships+comments"


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Loading the Instagram login page for user's to log in
        var fullURL = "\(KAUTHURL)?client_id=\(KCLIENTID)&redirect_uri=\(KREDIRECTURI)&response_type=token"

        var url = NSURL(string: fullURL)

        var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 40)
        myWebView!.loadRequest(request)

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do it is with a swift String:

```
var fullURL = "\(KAUTHURL)\(KCLIENTID)&redirect_uri=\(kREDIRECTURI)&response_type=token"
```

and you can then get an NSURL object from this String with:

```
var url = NSURL(string: fullURL)
```

To load the webView create a NSURLRequest:

```
var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 40)
yourWebView.loadRequest(request)
```

Comment: xCode presents the error "ViewController.Type does not have a member named KAUTHURL" and it will do this for all the other constants/variables

Comment: have you declared a var KAUTHURL?

Comment: Put the code where you declare the three constants in your question. Are they in the same class with the webview?

Comment: Put this: `var fullURL = "\(KAUTHURL)\(KCLIENTID)&redirect_uri=\(KREDIRECTURI)&response_type=token"` in your `viewDidLoad` method

Comment: That worked! didn't see your reply sorry. My only issue now is that "UIWebView? does not have a member named 'loadRequest'"

Comment: Unwrap the optional:  `myWebView!.loadRequest(request)`

Answer (score 0):

```
var KAUTHURL = "blah blah blah"
var KCLIENTID = "blah blah blah"
var kREDIRECTURI = "Blah blah blah"

var fullURL = String(format:"%s%s&redirect_uri= %s&response_type=token", KAUTHURL, KCLIENTID, kREDIRECTURI)
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
let fullURL = NSString(format: "%@%@&redirect_uri= %@&response_type=token", KAUTHURL,KCLIENTID,kREDIRECTURI)
```